# Scrolling in iOS Safari leaves this space at end of the WebApp

Tags: css, ios, angular, ionic-framework, safari

Safari on iOS 15+ collapses the footer when the page is scrolled. But my applications (ionic 3, 5, 6) don't expand to take up the full space.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle would not be possible, since its a client's project and code. But you can visit the site at megatrainer5.com

Comment: are you using safearea css padding?

Comment: Not explicitly, but I searched for the occurrence, and found it in the iOS build.